# How to access private variable from object instantiated inside class

Tags: c++, class, templates, object

I am trying to change a private variable of a class inside an object, which is initialized inside that class.
My intention can be drawn from the simple example below.
the `Increment` called from  `obj` should increase the `BaseClass::stuff`.

```
template <typename ObjectType>
class BaseClass{
 public:

  int Increment(){
    return obj.Increment();
  }

 private:
  int stuff = 0;
  ObjectType obj;
};

class ObjectType{
  public:     
   int Increment ()
   {
      return BaseClass<ObjectType>::stuff++;
   };
};

int main () {
  BaseClass<ObjectType> base;
  base.Increment(); // should increase stuff by 1;
}
```

One way I can think of is passing stuff as parameter to `obj.Increment()`.

Is there a way I can achieve this without passing it as a parameter?

Comment: Use `friend` keyword?

Comment: An object has no knowledge of what object it's a part of. If you add such knowledge you generally get very brittle code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example had a few errors.
Once fixed and added a `friend` specifier, it should look like this:

```
template <typename ObjectType>
class BaseClass{
public:
    friend ObjectType;

    int Increment(){
        return obj.Increment();
    }

private:
    static int stuff;
    ObjectType obj;
};

template<typename T>
int BaseClass<T>::stuff = 0;

class ObjectType{
public:     
    int Increment ()
    {
        return BaseClass<ObjectType>::stuff++;
    };
};

int main () {
    BaseClass<ObjectType> base;
    base.Increment(); // should increase stuff by 1;
}
```

Comment: I've tried running the code, got unsuccessful. ObjectType trying to approach BaseClass<T>::stuff (which is not an instantiated object) seems to be the problem how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The code in the answer compiles both on [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/Dym15I) and [GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/Z6pHQ8). I don't get your comment, sorry.

Comment: oh I missed the template<typename T> int BaseClass<T>::stuff = 0 part. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

1, the stuff is not a static public member, so it can not be directly implemented by ClassName::,  id you want to using "BaseClass::stuff++",  please change it as static public, this make all the objects of BaseClass share one stuff.

2, otherwise, ObjectType need "know" the BaseClass, ObjectType::Increment can increase the BaseClass stuff through some help funciton of BaseClass or make the ObjectType as a friend of BaseClass.

example code for ObjectType own BaseClass:

```
template <typename ObjectType>
class BaseClass{
public:
    void increaseStuff() {++stuff;}
.... 
}

class ObjectType
{
    BaseClass<ObjectType>& itsBase;
public:    
    ObjectType(BaseClass<ObjectType>& base) : itsBase(base) 
    int Increment ()
    {
       return itsBase.increaseStuff();
    };
};
```

but I think this design seems very strange, it means "I want to change something owned by me through others", why not directly change my things.
in this case, I think the stuff owned by ObjectType is more better.